# Next.js Video Placeholder Optimization

Tags: next.js

I have the following:

```
<video
  width={400}
  height={700}
  poster={insta_data?.thumbnail_url}
  className="lazy-image"
  controls
  preload="none"
  loading="lazy"
  className="lazy-image"                        
>
  <source 
    src={insta_data?.media_url}
    loading="lazy"
    width={400}
    height={700}
  />
</video>
```

The placeholders are being pulled through from Instagram video posts.

Right now, the images are huge and the placeholders are not optimised like Next/Image.

How would I go about resolving this?

Thanks in advance!